# find and replace in multiple files using PHP

Tags: php, file, replace, find

My folder contains about 500 files (html).
Each files contain this script

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "??????";
/* unit1 */
google_ad_slot = "??????";
google_ad_width = 120;
google_ad_height = 90;
//-->
</script>
```

I want to replace above code with this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/open.js"></script>
```

I used this code >>is good

http://pastebin.com/wuWupgBg

This find and replace in php only but no find and replace in html.
Can anyone make it find and replace in html files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really what we do here, but I would think you would just change line 17:

```
if( is_file( $path ) && substr($path, -3)=='php' && substr($path, -17) != 'ChangePHPText.php'){
```

to

```
if( is_file( $path ) && substr($path, -4)=='html' && substr($path, -17) != 'ChangePHPText.php'){
```

Though honestly, if you're doing that much text change, you may find a text editor that does string replacement in files to be much faster.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much (John C).
you are right.
i changed ($path, -3)=='php' to ($path, -3)=='html' but i didn't change ($path, -3) to ($path, -4), for this reason my error. thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

replace this code:

```
if( is_file( $path ) && substr($path, -3)=='php' && substr($path, -17) != 'ChangePHPText.php'){
```

with:

```
if( is_file( $path ) && substr($path, -4)=='html' && substr($path, -17) != 'ChangePHPText.php'){
```