# Recursively replace block of code in multiple files using FIND and REPLACE from external files

Tags: replace

I'm looking for a script to recursively replace a formatted block of text across all files and directories, with the search and replace text coming from external files. For example:

---

find.txt

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
    do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et 
dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
```

---

replace.txt

```
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat 
   non proident, sunt in 
       culpa qui officia 
       deserunt mollit anim id 
est laborum
```

---

And then a simple command along the lines of:

```
replace find.txt replace.txt /some/dir/*
```

[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24592503/find-and-replace-in-multiple-files-using-php) is close but not quite. But it looks like perl slurp might be part of the solution?

I don't care what language it's scripted in, as long as it's common and runs on Linux. Thanks a lot!

Comment: lust use `grep|sed` [Replace a String in Multiple Files in Linux](http://vasir.net/blog/ubuntu/replace_string_in_multiple_files). be carefull, you are going to work with too sharp objects

Comment: This is all I can find for sed:

http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq4.html#s4.23.3

But this won't work recursively across multiple files and directories.